# How do I change a str literal into a int literal in python?

Tags: python, string

I want to make a program in which the user types a function ("3*x+3", for example) and the program obtains the `Y` value from a specific `x` value.

The idea is that after the user types "3*x+3", the program replaces `x` for 3, and prints the value of `Y`, which in this case is 12.

This is the code I have made:

```
K=raw_input()
x=3
result = int(K)
print (result)
```

When I execute the program and write The function, an error appears:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3*x+3'

This only happens  when I type an expression with variables (even if they are previously defined). I think "int()" only works with str literals with only numbers, but I need it to work with numbers and variables (defined of course).

What should I use instead of of `int()` to change `3*x+3` from `str` to a `int`?

Comment: It is a lot more than just changing that to string... How are you planning on resolving x?  You will need to define a list of arithmetic operators and split the string on them into an array.  Then you will need to go through and actually perform the operations keeping in mind the right order of operations.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for your homework, this user recently asked something similar and is approaching the solution in a better way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837842/efficient-algorithm-to-compose-valid-expressions-with-specific-target

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind an additional dependency you can use [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) (a third party module, not exactly lightweight but supports a lot of options) and its `evaluate` function that does exactly what you need:

```
import numexpr
x = 3
K = "3*x+3"
result = numexpr.evaluate(K).item()
print(result)  # 12
```